# SQL Server 2012 \ VS 2010 - SQL syntax highlighting for custom file extensions

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, sql-server-2012

At work we have a variety of file extensions for our SQL code: `.PRC` for store procedures, `.TAB` for table scripts etc etc.

In previous versions of SQL Server Management Studio I could set each extension to use SQL syntax  highlighting in the `Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension` menu.

But in SQL Server 2012 the option for `"SQL Query Editor"` is gone:

[image]

Anyone know of a work around, I've tried some registry hacks to no avail)

Comment: Would switching to "double" extensions, like `.prc.sql` or `.tab.sql`, be an option?

Comment: @AndriyM I'll probably end up making a PowerShell script to do that, but it's another thing to remember and keep track of :(

Answer (score 4):

I added a `*` as a file extension that is handled by the SQL Query Editor and now I have the "*SQL Query Editor*" option in the drop down list of available editors.  The reg key I edited was:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management
>   Studio\11.0_Config\Editors{B5A506EB-11BE-4782-9A18-21265C2CA0B4}\Extensions

I matched the DWORD value to that of the "sql" extension.

EDIT:
It looks like this only worked for the session life of SMSS.  When I closed and reopened SMSS, the PRC mapping was erased and the DWORD key that I created was removed.  Hopefully I can find a way to keep it persistant.